# Boost Regex will not Compile

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am in the process of converting a PHP program to C++ for speed and memory management reasons.  Because [PHP uses Perl-Compatible syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php), I went the boost library which is [also uses the Perl syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)

Using Visual Studio Express 2013, I was able to use 6 of my 7 expressions as is. The one giving me fits is below

```
^([\w]+= {\s*(?:[a-f0-9]{2}\s+)*})\s*
```

Used in code as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
std::string regexError = R"~(^([\w]+= {\s*(?:[a-f0-9]{2}\s+)*})\s*)~";
boost::regex e(regexError);
```

This expression matches a string like this [Regex101 Example](http://regex101.com/r/aK1uN7/1):

```
MASKSUBSYS= { 00 af 01 02 }
```

I'm getting the following run time exception when calling `boost::regex e(regexError);`

> Unhandled exception at 0x7515C41F in RegexTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > at memory location 0x002DED5C.

It looks like there is no issue with blackslash escaping as you can see from the raw string read into memory.

[image: String in memory]

Like I said, only 1 of the 7 expressions will not compile straight out of PHP. I'm guessing it has something to do with regex fundamentals, but I am not versed enough in regex enough to recognize it. This isn't even the most complicated expression by far! Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure if `[\w]+` is really what you need `[]` should be a set of characters. I would use simply `\w+` there. Also I think you need to escape your `{` and `}`. Something like: `R"~(^(\w+= \{\s*(?:[a-f0-9]{2}\s+)*\})\s*)~"`

Comment: You are correct. You should have answered the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is that the curly bracket `{ }` metacharacters need to be escaped as well. And instead of placing a character class around `\w`, you can write it out by itself as follows.

```
R"~(^(\w+= \{\s*(?:[a-f0-9]{2}\s+)*\})\s*)~"
```

<kbd>[**Code Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9a2ef618b734c68)</kbd>

Comment: Duh!... I've never seen stacked-crooked.com. Thanks!